# Async static image with plotly (and kaleido)

Tags: python, asynchronous, plotly, mapbox, kaleido

I want to export static images for lots of plotly mapbox figures. Is it possible to run the export async? Pseudocode:

`await fig.write_image("images/fig1.png")`

Threading isn't an option because I have to export lots of images in parallel. Because of map box I expect the export to be IOBound.

Comment: You mean you want to make between exports a little delay

Comment: I want to accelerate image export by running multiple exports in parallel. Threading would work for a smaller number of exports, but max number of threads on a system is limited by the systems resources (ram). I want to export many images in parallel and expect the export to be IO bound because of mapbox (requests to tile server). Async would be a good choice for such a scenario, but only if plotly supports async.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not.